# php compare multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having problems comparing these arrays.

In a nutshell I want to check if `$tid_and_date_arr` exists within `$curr_vals`.  (Have a look.  It does, obviously.)

My logic is flawed, however, as the second time during the loop, `$tid_and_date_arr != $value[1]` so the value isn't skipped.

What am I missing?  Another loop inside the loop?

```
$curr_vals = array(array('tid' => 22, 'date' => 1497250800), array('tid' => 22, 'date' => 1497337200));

$tid_and_date_arr = array('tid' => 22, 'date' => 1497250800));

foreach($curr_vals as $value){
  if ($tid_and_date_arr == $value) {
    // skip these values as we've already saved them
    continue;
  }
  else {
   // save these values as they are new
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Does the required array exists or not according to your code?

Comment: According to the code posted, it does indeed exist, u_molder.  Something that almost threw me is that if the subarray that is returned from array_search is index 0, it's best to check like so:
    if ($result !== FALSE) {
     // it exists
    }
    else{
    // it doesn't exist
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with good old [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)?

```
$curr_vals = array(array('tid' => 22, 'date' => 1497250800), array('tid' => 22, 'date' => 1497337200));
//$tid_and_date_arr = array('tid' => 22, 'date' => 1497250800); -- this will output 0
$tid_and_date_arr = array('tid' => 22, 'date' => 1497337200);

$result = array_search($tid_and_date_arr, $curr_vals);

print_r($result);
```

This will output the key of the subarray you're looking for:

```
1
```

Comment: Ahh man...that's it!  Not sure how I missed that.  Too deep in the forest to see the trees, me thinks.  Thanks, Nordenheim!